# How do I include an entry image in an RSS Feed?

Tags: rss

A site (running EE 2.11.1) I am working on has the following RSS feed code:

```
{preload_replace:master_channel_name="blog"}
{exp:rss:feed channel="{master_channel_name}"}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

    <channel>

    <title>The corecubed Blog</title>
    <link>{channel_url}</link>
    <description>{channel_description}</description>
    <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
    <dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
    <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
    <dc:date>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />

{exp:channel:entries channel="{master_channel_name}" limit="10" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data|pagination"}
    <item>
      <title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
      <link>{title_permalink='blog/entry'}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink='blog/entry'}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
      <description>{exp:xml_encode}{blog_body}{/exp:xml_encode}</description>
      <dc:subject>{exp:xml_encode}{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/categories}{/exp:xml_encode}</dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}

    </channel>
</rss>

{/exp:rss:feed}
```

Each blog entry has a photo associated with it and I would like to add it to the fee. I tried adding it using the following:

```
<![CDATA[<img src="{blog_image}" alt="{title}">]>
```

But that broke the feed.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: "Broke the feed"? Broke how?

Comment: None of the content after that line of code shows up any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### your simple typo

[`<!\[CDATA\[`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) is closed with two brackets, `]]>`, not one, `]>`. ;-)

### a full explanation

Inside the `desciption` element, you can use HTML within a `<![CDATA[`:

```
<description><![CDATA[
    <img src="{blog_image}" alt="{title}">
    <hr />
    {blog_body}
]]></description>
```

Also, the [`enclosure`](https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltenclosuregtSubelementOfLtitemgt) element can be use to describe "a media object that is attached to the item". But not all parsers read it.

```
{blog_image}
    <enclosure url="{site_url}{url}" length="{file_size}" type="{mime_type}" />
{/blog_image}
```